# XPathEvaluate behave differently in other environments

Tags: c#, xpath, unity-game-engine, linq-to-xml

I am working on a game in unity and want to parse an XML file in a unity script,
my file starts with the line

```
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="16" height="12" tilewidth="64" tileheight="64">
```

and I want to get the map width attribute,

my code is :

```
var mapWidth = ((IEnumerable)tiledMapXmlRoot.XPathEvaluate("/@width")).Cast<XAttribute>().Select(a => Int32.Parse(a.Value)).First();
```

which is working right when I test it in visual studio, but fail when it runs in a unity script,
while debugging I can see it fails because **XPathEvaluate** returns an empty collection of type **System.Xml.XPath.SimpleSlashIterator**

while in visual studio the returned type is **System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator.EvaluateIterator** and it is a collection with one element as expected

how is it possible for the same code to work differently in two environments ?
I looked at the version of System.Xml.Linq and in visual studio its 4.0.0.0 while in unity (monodevelop script editor) it is 3.5.0.0 but looking at the library documentation the code should still work

Comment: Found the problem!
Unity works with monodevelop which support .net 3.5 and higher but unity itself only support .Net 2 and System.Xml.Linq only exist in .net 3.5 or higher

Comment: So post your solution as an answer and accept it, please. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and how and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`/@width` should return nothing, regardless of your source document. It selects the width attribute of the document node (called the "root node" in XPath 1.0), and document nodes do not have attributes. Any XPath processor that returns a result for this expression is non-conformant. The correct expression is `/*/@width`, which returns the width attribute of the outermost element in the document.

Comment: both "/@width" and "/*/@width" work right in visual studio with System.Xml.Linq 4.0.0.0
And non of them works in monodevelop with System.Xml.Linq 3.5.0.0