# Faster/shorter way to get an attribute's value in XElement with specified attribute in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Say I have something like:

```
<my-element>
    <property name="the property name" value="the value"/>
    <property name="some other property name" value="other value"/>
</my-element>
```

I'm using the following code to get ***"the value"*** from the property with name equal to ***"the property name"***.

```
string theValue = (
    from p
    in myElement.Elements("Property")
    where p.Attribute("name").Value == "the property name"
    select p.Attribute("value").Value
).FirstOrDefault();
```

This snippet does the job but I wonder whether there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about this *subjective better way*, but you can also use **Xpath**

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var val = (string)xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//property[@name='the property name']")
                      .Attribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `XPathSelectElement("/*/Property[@name='prefab']")`, the XPath you suggested is giving me some issues. Also tried `XPathEvaluate("/*/Property[@name='prefab']/@value")` but did't work either. I think the errors might be related to the [version of the library shipped with Unity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24978146/1436359).